# How to handle SVN errors using shell script?

Tags: svn, shell

Dear All,
I am trying to achieve **svn copy** operation with the help of shell script. The problem am having is to handle svn errors like **403**. Here goes a brief explanation about the problem,
My SVN structure looks like:

```
http://localhost/myproj/branches/dev/dev1
                                /testing/test1
                                /maintainance/m1
```

I am trying to write a shell script to achieve this task.
My Shell script expected behaviour:

```
Enter the Source url to be copied: http://localhost/myproj/branches/dev/dev1
Enter the new url name:http://localhost/myproj/branches/testing/test2
```

I don't want my script to show actual svn error to users, if user is not authorized in **testing** branch then svn shows **403 forbidden error**, all I want is to tell the user that **User is dont have access!! Not able to copy, contact administrator**. 
Is there any possibility of redirecting the svn error to some variable and depending on the value of that variable will show the messages to user. I want to do it in shell script.. pls guide me.

Thanks in advance
Srikanth B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect your outputs, using `>` and `2>`. As a very simple example:

```
#!/bin/ksh
svn copy $1 $2 2>&1 | grep '403 forbidden'
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then
  #The grep command was successful, i.e. '403 forbidden' was in the svn output
  echo No access.
  exit 1
else
  echo Complete
  exit 0
fi
```

This is *very* simple, and has a whole bunch of other problems, notably a complete avoidance of any other errors coming out of the svn command, but should give you an idea of how it could work.

Take a look at Wikibooks' page on [Bourne Shell Scripting: Files and Streams](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Files_and_streams) for more information on how this works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the timely answer. Thanks once again.